# multiple web api projects/services authentication

Tags: rest, web, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project where I have decided to divide business functionality into multiple service (i.e. Multiple Web api projects) where each service will serve specific functionality with it's own domain model.

In terms of project structure, I have 3 visual studio projects/sln.

1. Web-Api project for Booking (http://booking.testsite.com/api/...)
2. Web-Api project for Supplier (http://supplier.testsite.com/api/..)
3. AngularJS + Asp.Net MVC Application (web application) client application which will consume above API's

Both the Web Api projects are using the same SQL Server database via EF.

For me, the problem is where to implement Authentication? Should I create a separate service for authentication.

I am using token based authentication in my booing web-api project which works fine, but how can I use the same token to authorize supplier web api actions and controllers? unless I implement Account controller and IdentityUser in both the projects.

Is there a way to implement this without duplication login mechanism in both the web-api projects?

I also though about creating a third service (Web-Api project) just for authentication and call authentication service from supplier and booking services, but still not sure how it's going to work?

any help would be appreciated.

Extra question:
If I have 3 api service, booking, supplier and authentication and user is trying to access a protected resource on booking service by passing token.

Can I call authentication service by creating custom authorize attribute and forward that token to my authorize service to check if it's valid? also not sure how to implement CheckToken sort of action in authentication service Account controller.

Comment: I would go with one entry point for authentication. This will reduce stress when using SSO from other apps and centralize your token service. If you ever break your pieces apart you can always pull the authentication api into a web service and continue to use the same api within your other bits.

Comment: @hanz, I' facing a similar situation now. Could you please explain how you resolved this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I used Identity Server for authentication. This way I had centralized login application and all my services are secured via Identity Server so you would pass bearer token in to your services. see this example: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers